# ConfigSlurper bad result with nested values with same key

Tags: groovy

I'm trying to use the Groovy's ConfigSlurper in a projetct but it happens to have a weird behaviour when the same key appears two times in the configuration. Here is an example :

```
def struct = """
    node2 {
        subnode21="Test1"
    }
    root1 {
        node2 {
            subnode1="Test2"
            subnode2=node2.subnode21
        }
   }

"""
def config = new ConfigSlurper().parse(struct)
```

This will produce the following result :

```
[
    node2:[
        subnode21:Test1
    ],
    root1:[
        node2:[
            subnode1:Test2,
            subnode21:[:],
            subnode2:[:]
        ]
    ]
]
```

ConfigSlurper seems to consider that `subnode2=node2.subnode21` in the `root1` closure refers to `root1.node2` and not the `node2` closure declared above.

Is this a known limitation or am I missing something ?

Comment: I think you are not supposed to use references as rvalues, only values. I mean node2.subnode21 is not permitted on the right of the =

Comment: Well I've looked at the code of the classe since then and yes, it is permitted because the value is actually parsed and replaced by the correct value. The problem is (if I've understood correctly) that a stack is used for the keys researching, meaning that the first matching key will always be the one in the same object.